# Problem with glass. Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I create some glass material for Eevee. When the camera is close to glasses, then everything is rendered normally [image]. But if I move the camera away, then the detail decreases in the glasses. They become low res [image][image]. How to fix that? Material [image]
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tv0vuTxDTA0mOjbVgbrudOdyOlAjzYNT

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the 
bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us 
understand your scene and settings.  See [How to upload an image to a 
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491).

Comment: Hello :). I might be just short-sighted, but I cannot see the problem here. Are you sure just increasing the render resolution wouldn't help?

Comment: Yes, look at the shelf, it is normally displayed, and the glass is all in pixels. This should not work like that, I hope.

Answer (score 1):

Pixelation is visible on any of your glass cup object. Not only on far one from camera. The issue is just more visible on smaller cup than big one. So it has nothing to do with camera distance, but aliasing. Probably cost of eevee speed.

With Glass node **IOR to 1** (or above, ussually 1.43 is used) pixelation is gone.

[image]

**Alternatively**

You can try to set **Film > Filter Size > 3** in Render Properties.
Filter Size cares about aliasing, but in price of loos of sharpness (render became softer). [Blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/render_settings/film.html).

From top to down 0 / 1.5 / 3

[image]
[image]
[image]